# get files from multi severs(SFTP) using psftp

Tags: batch-file, sftp

I want to recive log files(txt) from many servers(SFTP) using psftp.
So i made batch files to access to severs.
But it stopped with Sent EOF message When i executed downlad_all.bat
What should i do to contine the process after the message?

---------- command log(After acesss to first server) ----------

```
Connected to <IP ADRRESS_01>
Remote working directory is ~~~
New local directory is D:/FindingLog\download
remote:/log/tmplog/20171018_2921.txt => local:20171018_2921.txt
remote:/log/tmplog/20171019_8310.txt => local:20171018_8310.txt
Sent EOF message
```

------- download_all.bat --------------

```
call down_from_01.bat
call down_from_02.bat
...
call down_from_XX.bat
```

------- down_from_01.bat --------------

```
psftp.lnk -b D:/FindingLog/auto.txt -l <ID> -pw <PASSWORD> -v <IP ADRRESS_01>
```

------- down_from_02.bat --------------

```
psftp.lnk -b D:/FindingLog/auto.txt -l <ID> -pw <PASSWORD> -v <IP ADRRESS_02>
```

------- down_from_XX.bat --------------

```
psftp.lnk -b D:/FindingLog/auto.txt -l <ID> -pw <PASSWORD> -v <IP ARDRESS_XX>
```

------- auto.txt --------------

```
lcd D:/FindingLog/download
mget "/log/tmplog/*.txt"
bye
```

Comment: Put a `quit` command at the end instead of `bye`.

Comment: You should also use the `-batch` option when executing `psftp`.

Comment: thanks you, i solved it.

Comment: Then post an answer.